# How to use CSS to Prevent a Asp.net BootStrap checkbox from disappearing on check

Tags: css, asp.net, checkbox, controls

I am building a website using ASP.NET Webforms and Bootstrap. I have a simple textbox but somewhere in the Bootstrap CSS it is causing it to disappear upon checking it. What would be a quick way to set some !important CSS to keep it visible whether it's checked or not.

Comment: First of all, don't use `!important`. Then with that out of the way, can you provide a [mcve]? Without it, you will not get any sane answers whatsoever.

Comment: Well the CSS is simple bootstrap.min.css. I have since figured out that this occurs in Microsoft Edge but not in IE. There, it renders correctly. It's just a basic .NET control for checkbox for example: 

<asp:CheckBox ID="MyID" runat="server" Text="My Text" />